# Show that $|1-\varphi_X (u)|\leq E\{ |uX| \}$

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Show that $|1-\exp\{ix\}|^{2}=2(1-\cos x) \leq x^{2}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Use this to show that $|1-\varphi_X(u)|\leq E\{|uX|\}$, where $\varphi_X(u) =E\{\exp(i\langle u,X\rangle)\}$ is the characteristic function.

We were given the hint that the power series for $\cos x$ is an alternating series. However, I'm not sure where that comes into play. For the first part, by using the definition of a square of a modulus, Euler's formula, and a trig identity, I got that $|1-\exp\{ix\}|^{2}=2-\sin^{2}x$. Now, $\sin^{2}x \leq x^{2}$, right? And so, $2-\sin^{2}x \leq 2-x^{2} \leq x^{2}$, right? So, I'm not sure hiw it's supposed to come into play in the first part, if at all.

The second part, showing that $|1-\varphi_X(u)|\leq E\{|uX|\}$ I am having the most trouble with. Any help you could give would be most appreciated!

Comment: You are definitely wrong with your use of the trig identities.  Try out the special case $x=0$.  The LHS of your proposed formula is 0, and the right hand side is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
1-\frac{x^2}{2} < \cos x < 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} \text{ if }x\text{ is near }0.
$$
You couldn't draw this conclusion if the series didn't have terms alternating in sign and (if $x$ is near $0$) getting smaller as the degree grows.

Hence
$$
x^2 - \frac{x^4}{12}\le2(1-\cos x) \le x^2.
$$

You should carefully distinguish between $x$ and $X$.  You're not doing that.

Before I say more, could you clarify whether you intend $X\sim N(0,1)$, as I'm guessing?

Comment: No. I do not intend that. Can you still help me?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Very often the letter $\varphi$ is used to represent the standard normal density function, and $f_X$ is the density of a random variable called $X$.  You've written $\varphi_X$.  What did you mean by that?  In another place, you've written $\varphi_x$, with a lower-case $x$.  Is that supposed to be the same thing, or something different?  You also wrote $E\{uX\}$ and also $E\{ux\}$.  Were those both supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: I meant the characteristic function. $\varphi_{X}(u) = \int{exp(i\langle u, X \rangle)}P^{x}(dx) = E\{exp(i\langle u,X \rangle)\}$. It's a Fourier transform of the probability measure. And yeah, those expectations are supposed to be the same.

Comment: OK, I've edited the question accordingly, putting $x$ and $X$ each where it belongs and clarifying what $\varphi$ is.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I've figured out the rest of the question as well. Thanks so much for your help!